# Webstorm remove project from Reopen Project list

Tags: webstorm

I have Webstorm version 9. I am trying to remove a specific project from the "Reopen Project" list.

I know there is the option to clear the entire list but i want to remove from it just a specific project. Screenshot is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On windows you can open the following file:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.WebStorm9\config\options\other.xml
```

and remove the line with the path for your project from the following node:

```
<option name="recentPaths">
```

Comment: **1)** Since PhpStorm v10 / WebStorm v11 this list is now stored in separate dedicated file named `recentProjectDirectories.xml` (same location) together with other relevant info: project groups + default folder location (for new projects). **2)** You can delete individual entries from Welcome screen (when all projects are closed) -- juts use `Del` (on some systems it could be `Backspace`) key or click on "x" icon when hovering over (if available).

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, great addition to the next next version